# What is required to open a bank in USA?

Tags: business, banking

What requirements should I meet to start a bank in USA?

What are the requirements in other countries?

Comment: Also you can start a credit union or saving and loan much easier than a bank.

Comment: @user3344003 I believe credit unions must be run "not for profit", meaning they are more like a co-op, not a business, like a bank is. So if you have too much profit, you need to distribute that back to the "members" (account holders). There's certainly money to be had in running a credit union, but nothing like the money in running a bank; this is probably a deal breaker to most people.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer in general terms, a "bank" in the US is either a commercial, for-profit bank, or a non-profit credit union. (There are many types of financial institutions that are under federal regulation: investment banks, commercial banks, brokerage houses, insurance companies, etc.)

There are full outlines at The Federal Reserve on the process to open a bank, who may open a bank, and what approvals are needed. All banks in the US fall under Federal Law, though there will be state laws that apply, too.

Start with http://www.federalreserve.gov/faqs/banking_12779.htm

> Starting a bank involves a long organization process that could take a
>   year or more, and permission from at least two regulatory authorities.
>   Extensive information about the organizer(s), the business plan,
>   senior management team, finances, capital adequacy, risk management
>   infrastructure, and other relevant factors must be provided to the
>   appropriate authorities.
>
> The proposed bank must first receive approval for a federal or state
>   charter. The Office of the Comptroller of the Currency (OCC) has
>   exclusive authority to issue a federal or "national bank" charter,
>   while any state (and the District of Columbia, Guam, Puerto Rico, and
>   the Virgin Islands) may issue a state charter. Before granting a
>   charter, the OCC or state must be able to determine that the applicant
>   bank has a reasonable chance for success and will operate in a safe
>   and sound manner. Next, the proposed bank must obtain approval for
>   deposit insurance from the Federal Deposit Insurance Corporation
>   (FDIC). Additional approvals are required from the Federal Reserve if,
>   at formation, a company would control the new bank and/or a
>   state-chartered bank would become a member of the Federal Reserve.
>
> All insured banks must comply with the capital adequacy guidelines of
>   their primary federal regulator (Federal Reserve, FDIC, or OCC). The
>   guidelines require a bank to demonstrate that it will have enough
>   capital to support its risk profile, operations, and future growth
>   even in the event of unexpected losses. Newly established banks are
>   generally subject to additional criteria that remain in place until
>   the bank's operations become well-established and profitable.

**For Credit Unions**, the National Credit Union Association responsible for the chartering of federal credit unions, which are nonprofit and cooperative in nature. https://www.ncua.gov/services/Pages/field-of-membership-chartering.aspx

> The Federal Credit Union Act ​(of  June 26, 1934) enabled credit
>   unions to be organized throughout the United States under charters
>   approved by the federal government. The purpose was to make credit
>   available to more Americans and promote thrift through a national
>   system of nonprofit, cooperative credit unions. The Federal Credit
>   Union Act also is the source of authority for all federally chartered
>   credit unions and governs the coverage and terms of insured accounts
>   at all federally insured credit unions. It also determines the
>   structure and duties of NCUA.

The Federal Credit Union Act: https://www.ncua.gov/Legal/Documents/fcu_act.pdf

**For the rest of the world**, Google is your best bet. All countries *(hopefully)*  have extensive regulations governing their banking industry, who may open a bank, and how those banks work - whether public, private or government owned - with the banking industry in the rest of the world.